# C# ASP.NET Core Cannot bind to a model of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormCollection'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, formcollection

I am getting the following error `An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormCollectionModelBinder' cannot bind to a model of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormCollection'. Change the model type to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormCollection' instead.`

This is when I use the following code:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Test test, FormCollection formCollection)
{        
    var feesAmountArray = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in formCollection.Keys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("FeesAmount-")))
    {
        feesAmountArray.Add(formCollection[item].ToString().TrimEnd(','));
    }

    var feesAmount = string.Join(",", feesAmountArray);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }

    return View(test);
}
```

Within the model `Test` I am using a `[Decimal]` attribute which is used in conjunction with a `ModelBinder`, but I am not wanting to bind to the form in anyway, I just want to bind to the model, so I am a little confused as to why this message is presenting itself.

The code relating to the ModelBinder can be found at:

[C# ASP.NET Core ModelBinder not Updating Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056221/c-sharp-asp-net-core-modelbinder-not-updating-model)

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: What do you expect to go into the `formCollection` value if you don't want it to be part of model-binding?

Comment: The main form is bound to the `Test` model but the form can include some dynamic fields created by jQuery, so I need primarily to validate the base `Test` model and in addition check for dynamic fields generated which do not exist in the `Test` model.

Comment: I've added extra code to address the need for FormCollection.

Comment: Ok, next question: Why can't you heed the advice of the error and just use `IFormCollection` instead of `FormCollection`?

Comment: Not sure if it justified a mark down. The reason for asking the question is that I didn't understand the error. I was only using model binding for certain attributes in the `Test` model, I wasn't using any model binding for the `FormCollection`, hence the confusion.

Comment: I didn't down vote (I generally don't), but I expect anyone that does would do so due to the fact that the solution was clear in the error message you provided.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two options:

1. Change your parameter to be IFormCollection
2. Remove it and instead access it through HttpContext.Form

Comment: How do I get the values in the Post method and save?

Answer (score 0):

Use like below and import `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` namespace.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(IFormCollection foFormCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                UserDataContext DBContext = new UserDataContext();
                Users Users = new Users();

                Users.EmpName = foFormCollection["EmpName"].ToString();
                Users.UserPassword = foFormCollection["UserPassword"].ToString();
                Users.flgIsActive = string.IsNullOrEmpty(foFormCollection["ActiveStatus"]) ? false : true;
                Users.EmployeeId = foFormCollection["EmployeeId"].ToString() == "0" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt64(foFormCollection["EmployeeId"]);

                Int64 Success = DBContext.addEditUser(Users)
                return RedirectToAction("pagename");
            }
            catch
            {
                return RedirectToAction("pagename");
            }
        }
```